# SQL Server - define target database name dynamically for MERGE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables on 2 different databases on the same server with SQL Server 2012.
I'm synchronizing those 2 tables using the MERGE statement but for the target table need to specify the database name dynamically in a query i.e [targetdb].[dbo].[tablename]

I have prepared a query and use EXEC to execute the dynamic query, but Is it possible to use variable value for [targetdb] database

Comment: Can't do it without dynamic SQL.

Comment: You have already prepared a dynamic query - just add the logic to use the appropriate 3 part (db.schema.table) name.